# Android master/detail Flow WebView reloading

Tags: android, webview, android-fragments, reload, savestate

I used the "master/detail Flow" code template and created a WebView in the list fragment. The WebView is used to load some data to create the Item, as far everything works well. But after opening an item and going back to the list fragment, the WebView starts to reload.

onActivityCreated (shorted)

```
@Override
public  void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.webView = new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    System.out.println("1");
    final Content cont = new Content();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
       //Code Removed
    });
    if(webViewBundle==null)
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.flb-herford.de/stupla.html");
    }
    else
    {
        webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    }


}
```

onPause():

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle=new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
}
```